# Why doesn't allocating memory chunks with malloc follow first-fit?

Tags: c, gcc, malloc, heap-memory

Codes below doesn't seem to follow the first-fit algorithm of glibc. I don't know where such difference comes out, just guessing it of different ubuntu version or glibc. I'm using Linux Ubuntu 19.04 and glibc 2.29. (glibc_2.29-0ubuntu2)

I tried compiling this code: https://github.com/shellphish/how2heap/blob/master/first_fit.c

And result is:

1st malloc(512): 0x55e9722a9260

2nd malloc(256): 0x55e9722a9470

3rd malloc(500): 0x55e9722a9580

As I know 3rd malloc ptr should be 0x55E9722A9260..

Comment: The code’s assertion that glibc `malloc` is first-fit appears to be incorrect. Per the source code of glibc 2.29 in `glibc/malloc/malloc.c`, it uses system memory mapping for requests of at least 128 KiB, is best-fit for requests of at least 512 bytes but below 128 KiB, is a caching allocator for requests up to 64 bytes, and is a hybrid between 64 and 512 bytes. (I did not examine all the source code to see if additional implementations are present.)

Comment: Why would you base your code on a specific `malloc` implementation? Wouldn't you prefer portable code?

Answer (score 0):

glibc -- which contains `malloc` and most other Standard C library functions -- is a tremendously complicated and evolving piece of software.  Your question (and the answers to it here) end up depending on four potentially *different* versions of glibc:

- the precise version of glibc that the author of https://github.com/shellphish/how2heap/blob/master/first_fit.c was using
- the compiled version of glibc that you're actually using when you compile and run your test program
- the version of glibc source that various answerers here are consulting
- the version of glibc that's documented in any documentation anyone's consulting while answering this question

Now, yes, in an ideal world, every version of every piece of software we ever use would have a precise and unambiguous version number on it, and all documentation would be perfectly up-to-date and would accurately describe every aspect of the exact version of software it's tagged with (even those aspects that changed the week before the documentation was released).

But here in the real world, the chance that somehow, somewhere, there's a mismatch between the four bulleted versions of glibc I referred to, a mismatch which ends up affecting the question you asked, is easily 100%.

Answer (score -1):

There is *absolutely* no guarantee made by malloc of how it hands out memory. If you need a particular algorithm, you should write your own or find one and modify it. It's not hard to write a simple malloc. It *is* hard to write a high-performance one that works for small chunks, large chunks, long-lived and short-lived chunks, and so on!

Comment: It is not true that “*absolutely* no guarantee” is made by `malloc`. The C standard does not make any guarantee, but various implementations of `malloc` are free to do so, and some are designed for various purposes and may specify their behaviors. In fact, the glibc `malloc` (or one part of it at least) states “For large (>= 512 bytes) requests, it is a pure best-fit allocator, with ties normally decided via FIFO (i.e. least recently used).” (glibc 2.29 `glibc/malloc/malloc.c`.)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I've just found out that unsorted bin is only used when requesting allocation with exactly same size. But still don't know why different size like 500 or 256 doesn't work for that so.